# How to access field name with space in Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The example code is below:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'First Name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = change.after.data();

      // ...or the previous value before this update
      const previousValue = change.before.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      //const name = newValue.name; //How does one accesses 'FIRST NAME'

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

If 'FIRST NAME' is replaced by 'name' it is easy, but my data comes from somewhere else where I have no control on the field names. So the field descriptions have spaces between. How do I read them please?

Comment: My first guess would be `newValue['First Name']`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use brackets notation of [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for that:

```
newValue["First Name"]
```

> In the `object[property_name]` syntax, the property_name is just a string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including `'1foo'`, `'!bar!'`, or even `' '` (a space).